# bad TCP network emulator

Tags: networking

Is there any tool that works like router and transforms reliable network traffic into not very reliable? I am looking for features like:

- Connection drops
- Split packets
- Lag

Problem is that I have an embedded device and I need to stress my ETH drivers and application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### WANem

Maybe give [WANem](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/) a try, I've used it myself and found it extremely helpful for such purposes.

> WANem is a Wide Area Network Emulator, meant to provide a real experience of a Wide Area Network/Internet, during application development / testing over a LAN environment.
>
> WANem thus allows the application development team to setup a transparent application gateway which can be used to simulate WAN characteristics like Network delay, Packet loss, Packet corruption, Disconnections, Packet re-ordering, Jitter, etc.

Comment: That is just what I was looking for. I now in testing and will report results.

Comment: I had 2 network cards in low end machine and I wanted that this should work like router, but I ended like setting this up like switch (which is even better)
So, I had problems setting up bridge (had no idea about that technology), and I found this link http://reloadin10.wordpress.com/2008/08/22/wanem-bridging-interfaces/ where I just changed bridge IP on static IP in my network, and gw on my network gw (getway). I have also found and tested http://www.wanulator.de/ and I can tell that it is simpler to use , but has limited capabilities and does not support random disconnection.